# Compound Poisson distribution and infinitely divisible probability generating function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-explanation

Let $(X_j)$ be a sequence of r.v. with common distributions $(f_j)$, $N$ be a r.v. having a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda t$. Let $S_N = X_1 + \cdots + X_N$. Then, $S_N$ has the compound Poisson distribution with a generating function $e^{-\lambda t + \lambda tf(s)}$, where $f(s) = \sum f_j s^j$ (a generating function of $(f_j)$). Let this generating function be $h_t(s) = e^{-\lambda t + \lambda tf(s)}$.

(Feller Vol.1, P.289-290) A probability generating function $h$ is called infinitely divisible if for each positive integer $n$ the $n$th root $\sqrt[n]{h}$ is again a probability generating function.

This follows that if $h_{t+r}(s) = h_t(s) h_r(s)$ for some positive integer $t$ and $r$, then $\sqrt[n]{h_t(s)} = h_{t/n}(s)$, and the right side is a probability generating function. Therefore, $h_t$ is infinitely divisible.
In addition, the author says that a probability generating function, which satisfy  $h_{t+r}(s) = h_t(s) h_r(s)$ must follows the compound Poisson distribution (i.e. $h_t(s) = e^{-\lambda t + \lambda tf(s)}$).

Then, I have the following theorem, which basically show that the converse is also true. I am struggling with the proof of this theorem .
[image]

(2.2) is $h_t(s) = e^{-\lambda t + \lambda tf(s)}$.

I don't particularly understand the statement highlighted with the purple line. Maybe I can express $\sqrt[n]{h(s)}$ as $- \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1/n \choose k} (1-h(s))^k$. This implies that $\sqrt[n]{h(0)} =- \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1/n \choose k} (1-h_0)^k$. But, I don't understand why $\sqrt[n]{h}$ vanishes. I am also not sure of how the author derives this convergence $\sqrt[n]{h(s)} \to 1$.

I would greatly appreciate if you elaborate the proof. Let me know if you need more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will write $p_{n,k}$ for the coefficient of $s^k$ in $\sqrt[n]{h(s)}$, that is
$$\sqrt[n]{h(s)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty p_{n,k} s^k.$$
Suppose that $h_0 = 0$. Then, since $h_0 = \left(\sqrt[n]{h(0)}\right)^n = p_{n,0}^n$, we would have $p_{n,0} = 0$. This is what Feller means by "the absolute term in the power series for $\sqrt[n]{h}$ would vanish". Then
$$\sqrt[n]{h(s)} = p_{n,1}s + \sum_{k=2}^\infty p_{n,k}s^k,$$
and this would imply that
$$h(s) = \left( p_{n,1}s + \sum_{k=2}^\infty p_{n,k}s^k\right)^n = p_{n,1}^n s^n + \cdots.$$
In other words, $h_0 = h_1 = \ldots = h_{n-1} = 0$. Since $n$ is arbitrary, we would then have $h_k = 0$ for every $k \geq 0$ which is obviously impossible as $h$ is a PGF. Thus $h_0 >0$.

From this, since $\sqrt[n]{h}$ is nondecreasing, we can deduce that for every $s \in [0,1]$
$$\sqrt[n]{h_0} \leq \sqrt[n]{h(s)} \leq \sqrt[n]{h(1)} = 1.$$
Letting $n \to \infty$, this yields $\sqrt[n]{h(s)} \to 1$.

Comment: Nice answer. I am wondering why the author says "the absolute term in power series".  It is confusing.

Comment: @shk910 maybe I can shed some light into that: the term absolute was often employed as to mean "independent of" or "this or that does not affect." If you are thinking on absolute value, this is called like so because is independent of sign; the absolute term in a power series is the only one that is independent of $s,$ etc.